# Cannot update field when located by object id, json parse error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection with content:

```
db.simplecollection2.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c312200508c979b46d21866"), "artistname" : "The 
Tea Party" }
```

When I change artistname with the following in mongo shell it works

```
db.simplecollection2.update(
{"_id":ObjectId("5c312200508c979b46d21866")},{"artistname":"new"})
```

However in javascript I get an Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 7 at JSON.parse (), although I parse a string to object and not object to object.. why is that?

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("simpledb");
      var myquery = JSON.parse("{\"_id\":ObjectId(\"5c31184bdb14729aa4806882\")}");
      var newvalues = { $set: {"artistname":"cool"} };
      dbo.collection("simplecollection2").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document updated");
        db.close();
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update using `ObjectID()`:

```
let id = new mongo.ObjectID("5c312200508c979b46d21866");
db.simplecollection2.update({ "_id" : id }, { "artistname" : "new" });
```

[Read More](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ObjectID.html)

Answer (score 0):

The line where you call JSON.parse fails because the argument is not a JSON. If you do `JSON.stringify({"_id":ObjectId("5c312200508c979b46d21866")})` you'll see that it can't turn that into a string either. The reason being that JSONs can contain strings, booleans, numbers, and arrays. `ObjectId("5c312200508c979b46d21866")` doesn't resolve to something the browser knows, even though it makes sense in the shell. However, I think if you pass it as a string, it should work as a query for the db.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("simpledb");
      var myqueryObj = {
          _id: 'ObjectId("5c312200508c979b46d21866")'
      };
      var myquery = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myqueryObj));
      var newvalues = { $set: {"artistname":"cool"} };
      dbo.collection("simplecollection2").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document updated");
        db.close();
      });
```